# Feitian java card h10cr default key

Tags: smartcard, javacard

I want to install an applet on h10cr Feitian Java Card. The problem is I don't have the default key.

The seller does not have it, either. Could anyone help me?

Can I use this command with Feitian Java Card?

```
Open_sc -security 0 -keyind 0 -keyver   0 -key "default key"
Keyderivation visa2
```

Answer (score 1):

My h10cr feitian java card default key was 4041....4f